# How to change Java Build Path for Android in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a build problem with a specific file that I'm not being able to change the path on my Android project. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

How do I change this Path: **/Users/apple/Downloads/dolphin_player/p/libs** shown in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from the libraries tab.  You cannot do it from the order and export tab.

Answer (score 1):

On the **libraries** tab, remove or edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, just follow these steps,

- Right click on your project, select properties,
- From the dialogbox select "Java Compiler" in left part, see image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the which version of java you are using.Just go to library tab and do following.

If you are using the **1.6** version of java the whenever you want to add any third party jar files you have to add it by **adding external jar** file in the library option.

If you are using the **1.7** version of java then you have to make a folder called **libs** and put the all the external jar files in this folder. It will automatically add the files to yous build path and add it in **"Android Dependencies"**.